# What is equivalent of TRAVIS_TEST_RESULT in GitHub Actions

Tags: travis-ci, github-actions

I'm rewriting a CI/CD pipeline from Travis to Github Actions. I'd like to know what is equivalent of Travis environment variable [TRAVIS_TEST_RESULT](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables) in GitHub Actions?. Basically, I'd like to know if the status of an action / step filed or succeed. As for now there is no [default environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) in GitHub Actions that would match what I want to express.

Answer (score 0):

I found work around it. Instead of looking at github's [default environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) (or lack of it). I fetched related state from workflow's [context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contexts). I used `${{ job.status }}` context.

**Debugging workflow's context:**

```yaml
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master, actions ]
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches: [ master, actions ]
jobs:
  debug:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Debug
        env:
          JOB: ${{ toJson(job) }}
          CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
        run: |
          echo $JOB
          echo $CONTEXT
```